# Работа с метками(тегами)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Возник вопрос выделение(стилизация) меток(тегов) за количеством записей 
То есть к примеру
Есть 3 метки которые есть в

1. Текст 1 - в 5 записей
2. Текст 2 - в 20 записей
3. Текст 3 - в 1 записе

Нужно выделить(стилизировать) каждую метку к примеру разделить на 2 категории для меток(тегов) в которых записей меньше 20 зделать их одним цветом, а для тех что 20 и больше другим цветомю

Все что я находил - это работа с популярными метка (то есть по кол-ству просмотра), но не по самому количеству.

Буду благодарен за название плагина(модуля) или подсказку как решить данную задачу.

Comment: Что значит "выделение" что за "за количеством"?

Comment: Немного изменил сам вопрос

Comment: Смотреть на МЕТКИ по кол-ву  просмотров - это что-то из области фантастики. Группировкой по кол-ву можно заморочиться, но точно это надо? Остальное в ответе.

Comment: ну клиент, хочет стилизацию именно по "КОЛИЧЕСТВУ", возможно ошибся (написав по количеству просмотров) сейчас реализовано по количеству использования

Comment: В ответе и рассказано про нужное тебе количество. Количество использования= сколько постов с этой меткой. Какие ещё "количества" могут быть?

Comment: На сайте есть приблизительно 40 меток и вот часть из них в дужках указано количество  - AIRBUS A330 (7),  AN-124 (9),  BIRDS OF EUROPE (163), BIRDS OF ICELAND (92), BIRDS OF POLAND (17), BIRDS OF THE NORTH (117). Надо разделить на 3 групы и выделить каждую из них по количестве постов с метками ,  для AIRBUS A330 (7),  AN-124 (9), BIRDS OF POLAND (17) сделать красным цветом, BIRDS OF EUROPE (163), BIRDS OF THE NORTH (117) - синим, BIRDS OF ICELAND (92) и зелёным.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно выделить(стилизировать) каждую метку

Стандартное облако меток выводит метки по количеству **использования** в порядке уменьшения. И у каждой позиции метки в этом облаке есть уникальный css-класс. `tag-link-position-1`, `tag-link-position-2` и тд.